# xpath query in a servlet gives exception

Tags: java, servlets, xpath, thread-safety

I have a Document object initialized in the init() method of the servlet and use it in the doPost() method to service the requests.

selectNodeList() xpath query gives exception when the servlet services many request at same time.
The Exception is shown below:

```
Caused by: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: -1
    at org.apache.xpath.XPath.execute(XPath.java:331)
    at org.apache.xpath.CachedXPathAPI.eval(CachedXPathAPI.java:328)
    at org.apache.xpath.CachedXPathAPI.selectNodeList(CachedXPathAPI.java:255)
    at org.apache.xpath.CachedXPathAPI.selectNodeList(CachedXPathAPI.java:235)
    at com.pro.bb.servlets.Controller.getDataOrPeriodForReport(Controller.java:511)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at org.apache.xpath.XPathContext.pushCurrentNode(XPathContext.java:808)
    at org.apache.xpath.axes.PredicatedNodeTest.acceptNode(PredicatedNodeTest.java:447)
    at org.apache.xpath.axes.AxesWalker.nextNode(AxesWalker.java:409)
    at org.apache.xpath.axes.WalkingIterator.nextNode(WalkingIterator.java:176)
    at org.apache.xpath.axes.NodeSequence.nextNode(NodeSequence.java:320)
    at org.apache.xpath.axes.NodeSequence.runTo(NodeSequence.java:474)
    at org.apache.xpath.axes.NodeSequence.setRoot(NodeSequence.java:257)
    at org.apache.xpath.axes.LocPathIterator.execute(LocPathIterator.java:257)
    at org.apache.xpath.XPath.execute(XPath.java:308)
```

Help me sort out the issue.

Comment: where is this Document declared?  if it's a private variable in your servlet you have a concurrency problem i guess.!

Comment: thanks.. so, how do resolve this issue?

Comment: Synchronize the access to Document. Or maybe better create the instance of Document localy in the doPost()

Comment: I tried creating instance of Document in doPost().. after sometime I get the java heap space error. i use tomcat server. the xml file is around 3MB.. what can i do?

Comment: You can config higher heap size when you start your server. Honnestly, you should never use global variable in Servlet since its heavy multi threaded componant.  Pump your heap size to avoid OutOfMemoryException.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CachedXPathAPI` class is not thread-safe. If you're using it in the servlet, you have to manualy take care for synchonizing access (or use multiple instances).

From the [Apache Xalan-j javadoc](http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/apidocs/org/apache/xpath/CachedXPathAPI.html#CachedXPathAPI%28%29):

> Note that any particular instance of [CachedXPathAPI](http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/apidocs/org/apache/xpath/CachedXPathAPI.html) must not be operated upon by multiple threads without synchronization; we do not currently support multithreaded access to a single [DTM](http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/apidocs/org/apache/xml/dtm/DTM.html). Similarly, any particular instance of [CachedXPathAPI](http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/apidocs/org/apache/xpath/CachedXPathAPI.html) must not be operated upon by multiple threads without synchronization.

Comment: thanks.. is there any other alternative way to handle this scenario?

Comment: I think that serving data from XML is a bad idea. You should transform the XML to a structured Java object on `init()` and then serve values from that object without any further XML processing on each request.

Answer (score 0):

Try Saxon. Saxon document instances and cached queries/stylesheets/xpath expressions are all fully thread-safe.